# How to select the equivalent row for another column of the max(column) in group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to make a change in the Sql below to make **CreatedOn** return the selected record of the Max(Value). You can observe the **-- todo line**.

> Should return: **2/01/2015** and **8/01/2015** as you can see in **Query Result**,
>   but the **Max(CreatedOn)** will select the max and not the referent record
>   of the **Max(Value)**.

**Sql**

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT 
   CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, CreatedOn),DATEPART(WEEK, CreatedOn)) Week, 
   MAX(CreatedOn) CreatedOn, -- todo: this should return 2/01/2015 and 8/01/2015
   MAX(Value) AS MaxValue
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, CreatedOn),DATEPART(WEEK, CreatedOn))
```

**Table 1:**

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║ Id ║ CreatedOn ║ Value ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ 1/01/2015 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║ 2/01/2015 ║     2 ║
║  3 ║ 8/01/2015 ║     4 ║
║  4 ║ 9/01/2015 ║     2 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```

**Query Result:**

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║  Week  ║ CreatedOn ║ MaxValue ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ 2015 1 ║ 2/01/2015 ║        2 ║
║ 2015 2 ║ 8/01/2015 ║        4 ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

> ***Edited**: I need to return **8/01/2015** because it is the correspondent row of the MaxValue (4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` over a partition of each week (`PARTITION BY Week`), ordering by the descending value (`ORDER BY Value DESC`) to 'rank' each record within the week. Selecting the row with the highest value in each week is then simply the top ranked row in each partition (`WHERE Rnk = 1`). I've used CTEs to prevent the repetition of the Week calculation.

```
WITH Weeks AS
(
   SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, CreatedOn),DATEPART(WEEK, CreatedOn)) Week,
          Id, CreatedOn, Value
   FROM Table1
),
Ranked As
(
  SELECT Week, CreatedOn, Value,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Week ORDER BY Value DESC) Rnk
  FROM Weeks
)
SELECT Week, CreatedOn, Value
FROM Ranked
WHERE Rnk = 1;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d68b/6)

Comment: I don't know if everyone understood what I needed, but I noticed it can be confusing... the reason why I need 9/01/2015 is only because the max 4 had its correspondent date 9/01/2015 (not because 9 was the max date). is this what everyone understood?

Comment: @RogerOliveira I believe your are looking for the groupwise maximum - unfortunately it seems that in your sample data, the max date in each week ALSO has the max value, meaning that your original, independent application of `MAX()` on `CreatedOn` ad `Value` should have also coincidentally worked?

Comment: @StuartLC yes, my bad, I did a wrong sample data, I can change it if necessary... but what I need, is in fact the correspondent CreatedOn from the row of the max(value),

Comment: @RogerOliveira [Here's an updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aea7b/1) with data proving that the created on in the day of week with the highest value is returned, even if it isn't the last day in that week.

Comment: Exactly! It is impressive, I am really grateful, you are a legend and Stackoverflow  saved my day again! @StuartLC

Answer (score 2):

Your query is correct, however there is a problem with the date format. You are reading your dates as dd/mm/yyyy while DB is interpreting them as mm/dd/yyyy.

So a quick fix is, use proper format while inserting values like

```
insert into Table1 ( id ,  CreatedOn,  value)
values (1 , '01/01/2015' ,    1 )
insert into Table1 ( id ,  CreatedOn,  value)
values (2 , '01/02/2015' ,     2 )
insert into Table1 ( id ,  CreatedOn,  value)
values (3 , '01/09/2015' ,     4 )
insert into Table1 ( id ,  CreatedOn,  value)
values (4 , '01/08/2015' ,     2)
```

I tried in this worked. Let me know if you need SQLFiddle of the same.

Comment: The interpretation of dates from strings depends on the connection's DateFormat. For Example, see the [difference here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/946). The most Agnostic string format is YYYYMMDD although yyyy-mm-dd is usually good enough.